# Is complement and not effectively the same in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

Suppose I run the following `map` operation using `not`:

```
core=> (map (comp not) [true false true false])
(false true false true)
```

Suppose I run the following `map` operation using `complement`:

```
core=> (map (complement identity) [true false true false])
(false true false true)
```

My question is: **Is `complement` and `not` effectively the same in Clojure?**

(Except that `compliment` acts a little bit like `comp`ose in creating a `partial`)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They are same in terms that you can achieve same results with little changes (like you did in your code sample). This becomes very clear if we look at `complement` source:

```
(source complement)
=>
(defn complement
  "Takes a fn f and returns a fn that takes the same arguments as f,
  has the same effects, if any, and returns the opposite truth value."
  {:added "1.0"
   :static true}
  [f]
  (fn
    ([] (not (f)))
    ([x] (not (f x)))
    ([x y] (not (f x y)))
    ([x y & zs] (not (apply f x y zs)))))
```

They are however very different in their meanings - `not` is operating on values, and it returns values (`true` or `false`). `complement` operates on and returns functions.

This might seem like an implementation detail, but it is very important in expressing your intensions - using `complement` makes it very clear that you are creating a new function, whereas `not` is used mostly in conditional checks.

Comment: Which one do you think is more idiomatc? `comp not` or `complement`?

Answer (score 1):

Similar but not the same. `complement` returns a function while `not` is evaluated immediately.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a clarification on your question: `(comp not)` is pretty much identical to `(complement identity)` since `(comp not)` results in a function that does the same thing.